# While removing mysql completely mysql-config-apt files are left and gives error

Tags: 20.04, mysql

I tried uninstalling the mysql from my system and executed the following command,

`sudo apt remove mysql*`

And got the following response,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
E: Unable to locate package mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb.1
```

How do I remove these mysql apt config deb files?

EDIT 1:

Also, when trying

`apt list -i | grep mysql`

We get following response,

`WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

Answer (score 0):

If `apt` is unable to do this for you, it may be necessary to use `dpkg` instead:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-apt-config
```

From here, be sure to update `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt autoclean
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When executing, `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-apt-config`. Gets this response
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql-apt-config which isn't installed

Comment: Then this may be a fragment. You may be able to remove references to it with a `sudo apt update` and/or `sudo apt autoclean`.